# MASM Macro syntax error?

Tags: windows, assembly, macros, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to write a macro in MASM I have looked over the syntax I've looked online and I've looked in my book. I'm using the same syntax but it keeps giving me an error for either the Macro call itself or the parameter I'm trying to use. I have no clue what's wrong and I feel stupid for asking the stack overflow community but I've run out of options please help. Code below.

```
; Description: Bit manipulation using macros
; 
; Revision date:

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
number dword 1
.code

main PROC
mReverse number; MAcro call

exit
main ENDP

mReverse MACRO number
local label , count
.data
count dword 7
.code
Wh1le&label:
    cmp count, 0
    jne Do1&label
    jmp endWh1le&label
    Do1&label:
        rol &number,1
        dec count
        jmp Wh1le&label
endWh1le&label:
ENDM
END main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the MASM-preprocessor reaches the line `mReverse number; MAcro call`, it doesn't know the "directive" `mReverse` because the macro will be defined later. Move the whole `mReverse MACRO...ENDM` block to the beginning of the program.

Comment: THANK YOU :D I was going off of what i've done when i write procs